# Presenting comparable data series with varying frequency

Tags: info-visualisation, tables, data-frequency

I've a data design challenge that requires the presentation of data where the data is comparable (can be plotted or presented as a table) but who's data points are inconsistent.

Inconsistency occurs in that one data series will consist of monthly data points whereas a comparable series will be represent with weekly data points that in turn can be aggregated to provide a monthly average.

The challenge is to present the data in an accessible (comprehensible) way.

As for a little background the data is of type price / value / weight and used for financial analysis and market forecasting purposes.

Because of the financial nature examples and practices are hard to come by, I've a few ideas of how to present this type of data but would like to hear if anyone can point me in the direction of any design patterns I can base further thoughts on?

I've added this example - don't worry about the data

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF9JPC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: If you have some ideas of your own currently can you post one of these so we can get a visual idea of where you're coming from?

Comment: We may be looking at his best idea for a tabular view. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A zoomable graph/chart is the best way I've seen to present multi-scale data over time, or to look at the same data over different time scales. [Weatherspark](http://weatherspark.com/) is a good example of a zoomable chart. You can use the mousewheel to expand or shrink the time scale, and the graph dynamically adjusts how it displays the information (as an average, as a range, etc).

Comment: Thanks Myrddin, we are having to include this type of data representation and functionality based on the data we need to include in a tabular form